# SQL- Selecting different fields from different tables based on Condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables like below:

**Table1:**

```
>  ACCOUNT    datetime     Doc1   
        -----|------------|-------
       | A   | 04/01/2019 | 399 
       | A   | 23/03/2019 | 244
       | A   | 04/03/2009 | 555
       | B   | 08/11/2009 | 300
       | B   | 05/11/2019 | 200
```

**Table 2:**

```
  >  ACCOUNT  datetime     Doc2   
        -----|------------|-------
       | A   | 04/10/2019 | 7832 
       | A   | 23/07/2018 | 6325
       | B   | 08/10/2019 | 3877
       | B   | 03/02/2010 | 3267
```

My tables have different fields, I mean both of them have `ACCOUNT` and `datetime` but one of them have `Doc1` and the other `Doc2`.

our requirement is to read for each `account` the related `Doc` ( which can be `Doc1` or `Doc2`) in which the datetime is the recent date.

**This will be the result:**

```
>     ACCOUNT datetime     Doc   
        -----|------------|-------
       | A   | 04/10/2019 | 7832  (Table2)
       | B   | 05/11/2019 | 200   (Table1)
```

I can not achieve it. 
I can find the `MAX(datetime)` but can not read the related `Doc` (which can be `Dcc1` or `Doc2`)

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Sin

Comment: _Columns_, not fields.

Comment: Store dates using a correct date data type. And see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions and `union all`:

```
select t12.*
from (select t12.*,
             row_number() over (partition by account order by datetime desc) as seqnum
      from ((select account, datetime, doc1
             from table1
            ) union all
            (select account, datetime, doc2
             from table2
            )
           ) t12
      ) t12
where seqnum = 1;
```